# MongoDB $lookup - Convert String to Number

Tags: mongodb, lookup

I need to make a simple MongoDB $lookup request with my two collections :

**commands**

```
{
   clientId: {type: 'String', default: null},
   reference: {type: 'String'}
}
```

**clients**

```
{
   _id: {type: 'Number', default: 0},
   name: {type: 'String', default: null}
}
```

How to do that with a simple mongoDB query ?

For now, I have that :

```
db.commands.aggregate({
    $lookup: {
        from: 'clients',
        localField: 'clientId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'clientId'}
    },
});
```

But clientId field is always an empty array. I think I need to temporaly convert clientId field into a Number ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Data type for both the `localField` and `foreignField` should be same.

Comment: Is there a way to convert them just for this query ?

Comment: What version of mongodb you are using?

Comment: My mongoDB version is 3.4.2

Comment: Then not possible you have to upgrade to 4.0 to convert them

Comment: Okay, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `$toInt`, new in version 4.0.

```
db.commands.aggregate([
  {$project: {clientId: { $toInt: '$clientId'}}},
  {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'clients',
        localField: 'clientId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'clientId'
    }
  }
]);
```